# "Could not find installable ISAM" - ".xlsx" reading no errors but reading "xls" file Get that error on windows 7 32bit

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

```
 OleDbConnection excelConnection=null;
            try
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(excelFileName).Equals(".xls"))
                {
                    string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFileName + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
                    excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                }
                else
                {
                    string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\";";
                    excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);

                }
                excelConnection.Open(); ***// this statement get the error!!!***
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

**This is my connection strings:**

string 1.

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\~Projects IW\Desktop APPS\Maga\Book1.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"
```

string 2.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\~Projects IW\Desktop APPS\Maga\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;";
```

When reading xls file using connection string 1 get error

> "could not find installable isam"

But reading xlsx file using connection string 2 ;it is works fine: NO Errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first connection string includes `Excel 8.0 Xml;` which will not work. Use `Excel 8.0;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Error is because of connection

for **.xls** try this connection string:

```
  StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
```

and for **.xlsx** try this connection string:

```
StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
```